# How to search and replace text files with "/"

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I have a text file with `./.` and need to replace it with `0|0`.

The file is too big to open in Gedit and do it by hand.

Can I do it using `sed`?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. In this case it's useful to choose a different delimiter like `_`, this way you don't have to escape the slash:

```
sed 's_\./\._0|0_'
```

Example:

```
$ cat test
./.
$ sed 's_\./\._0|0_' test
0|0
```

Add

- `-i` to change the file in place rather than print the output to stdout,
- `-i.b` to do so and save a backup with `.b` as an extension and
- `g` to the end of the expression to change multiple occurences per line rather than just the first one (→ `'s_\./\._0|0_g'`).

#### Explanations

- `s/A/B/` – replace `A` by `B`, the same as `s_A_B_`, `ssAsBs` or whatever you can imagine:

  > Any character other than backslash or newline can be used instead of a slash to delimit the BRE and the replacement. <sup>[[source](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/sed.html)]</sup>
- `s/A/B/g` – replace `A` by `B` and do it `g`lobally, so don't stop doing it after the first finding (per line!)
- `\./\.` – the literal string `./.`, a dot needs to be escaped with a backslash because they are part of [basic regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) and else would take any character, matching `a/a`, `a/b`, `///` and so on
- `0|0` – the literal string `0|0`

Comment: Was about to post the same information. The picket fence is so hard to read (and debug).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do that with sed.
You need to escape `.` and `/` with a `\`.

```
sed -i.bak 's/\.\/\./0|0/g' file
```

`-i.bak` will make sed edit the file in place but creates a backup file with .bak extension.
The `g` at the end means "global" --> Replaces all occurencies.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you asked for `sed` command to fulfill your requirement, you can also give a try to `ex` command.

```
ex -sc '%s/\.\/\./0|0/g|x' file
```

`%` select all lines

`s` for substitute

`g` replace all instances globally

`x` write if changes made and exit

Example:-

```
$cp file file.bak
$cat file
./.
$ex -sc '%s/\.\/\./0|0/g|x' file
$cat file
0|0
```